# Encoding data in transaction as only objective

Tags: transactions

I want to use the Stellar Blockchain to encode 32 bytes hashes, using https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html#memo. Registering this data is my only objective, so I'd like to know what's the transaction type that would make more sense to use. I am trying it with `Manage Data`, using a `Name` but no value, so it doesn't have any real effect.

Is that a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

It smells like a dirty workaround but since a transaction is required to have at least one operation, there seems to be no other choice than adding a dummy operation.

ManageData with empty value will remove the data entry but also fail if the entry does not exist. Instead you could set a dummy value repeatedly.

I could as well think of these other possible operations:

- Payment: to yourself
- SetOptions: set any property to it's same current value